# How do I call an API in another project but same solution without hard-coding the url?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects. One for my front-end angular code. Another for Web API. When I'm in the front-end project, I want to make a call to an API in my other project.

The Web API tutorials I have seen show a relative url involving /api such as this:
    $http.get("/api/trivia")

That works great if the javascript is in the same project as Web API, but it's not for my Solution.

I can hard-code the url to my API's localhost port and it works fine, but of course that won't work when I deploy the app to Azure. How should I be handling these urls?

Thank you.

Comment: You can inject a constant on you module and use it as the root path. You can then append the api path to the root path for making the api calls. The value of the constant you need to pick dynamically from the server side configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a $http with full url  (http://...) it directly look at given address. But when you specify relative path (without http://...) it look at your current site + given relative path url.
So **If your api also hosted in same site** you can still make the reference as $http.get("/api/trivia") or else as you said if you know where you host your site in Azure you can make it hard code in in your script.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is "it's not possible". If I have the front end javascript and my web api in two different projects, I'll need to juggle hard-coded urls  when testing and deploying. Thanks.

Comment: its not about having multiple projects, host your web api also in same iis site\ port and you can work with relative path method.
and you do not need to have hard coded values every where. create config file for your app and set the globally used variables there, inject the dependency in your controller\ service and refer the config value.